# Авторасширение диапазона формулы при добавлении строки в Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, формулы, google-docs

Вопрос такой. Есть формула `=Vlookup(base!G2;A16:G19;3;0)`. В ней указан диапазон A16:G19 при добавлении строки в 19 строке диапазона, диапазон автоматически не увеличивается (как в excel'e). Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это действительно немного странно, что при добавлении строки ниже, примыкающий сверху диапазон не расширяется.

Есть три основных пути, которые не используют дополнительные инструменты, чтобы это решить:

- Добавление строки сверху последней. В этом случае диапазон расширяется автоматически.
- Подсчет количества строк в заданном диапазоне. Это не всегда просто, но иногда возможно. `=VLOOKUP(Base!G2;INDIRECT("A16:G" & MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A));ROW(A:A)))));3;0)`
- Задание неопределенного размера диапазона `=VLOOKUP(Base!G2;A16:G;3;0)`

[Пример решения](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EU88TrWZ7sQPZHHNe6ZLpuoWB1bgjZV7f2cN5y9fnFo/edit?usp=sharing)

С большой вероятностью имеет смысл отправить форму обратной связи, непосредственно из Таблицы, с предложением изменить функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Как обойти это ограничение, не скажу.

Изначально задайте диапазон с большим количеством строк.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная задача автозаполнения формул в новых ответах, приходящих через гугло-формы (форма при ответе добавляет в Spreadsheet новые строки).
Arrayformula вам поможет. 
Пример например [тут](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/lZpA-egYvac/33JvW676DBYJ)